# adding numbers on String board

Tags: java

I have a portion of code below displaying a board of words.

```
int a ;
String s = "\nLLUA\nUELB\nPIEA\nNMET";  

String board = "";

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    a = (int) s.charAt(i);
    if ((a >= 97 && a <= 122) || (a >= 65 && a <= 90)) {
        board =    board  + s.charAt(i) + " | ";

    } else if (board != "" && board.length() != 1) {
        System.out.println(board);
        board = "";
    }else if(board != "" && board.length() == 1){
        board = "";
    }

}        

if (board != "" && board.length() != 1){

    System.out.println("|" + board);
}
```

I would like to add numbers on each row and each column of the board, as shown below:

[image: Board with numbers]

Can anyone please help me !!! using regex, table, ArrayList is not allowed.

Thank you.

Comment: Your code displays something very different^^

Comment: Sorry !!! Just corrected the s string. Thank you

Comment: Please, anyone here to help me ?

Comment: hello !!! Mercury calling Pluto !!!!

Comment: up,i  answered    you

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Things you need to improve :

- *equality* for `Strings` (like every other object) have to be done with `equals()`
- use `StringBuilder` to concatenate multple `Strings`

---

**2.** I would have done it differently ([Working example](https://ideone.com/3YHzaN))

- create the first line of indexes of columns
- iterate over each word and create the index of line and then the letters of the current word

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "\nLLUA\nUELB\nPIEA\nNMET";
    String[] words = s.trim().split("\n");             //[LLUA, UELB, PIEA, NMET]

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("     |");

    for (int i = 1; i < words[0].length() + 1; i++) {
        sb.append(i).append(" | ");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        sb.append("\n").append("| ").append(i + 1).append(" | ");
        for (char c : words[i].toCharArray()) {
            sb.append(c).append(" | ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
/*
     |1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 
| 1 | L | L | U | A | 
| 2 | U | E | L | B | 
| 3 | P | I | E | A | 
| 4 | N | M | E | T | 

*/
}
```

Comment: thank you. But I cant use regular expressions, regex, table, arraylist. Homework restrictions. I can only use String, Math, System and Scanner.